# Creating an app and it can't find the target location for sdk

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I've also tried changing the preferences and the target can't be found there iether. sdk is installed in my documents folder. Please help...trying to create an app

Comment: What ide are you using? Eclipse, netbeans...

Comment: I'm using eclipse ide for developing.  
My file says andoid_r11-sdk-windows{1} and the sdk is not in a specific file. It's just in that area. When I tried to paste it to file, eclipse still couldn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

In Preferences -> Android you can set the SDK Location
You should point it to .../android-sdk-windows (suppossing you are using Windows)

Comment: I'm using eclipse ide for developing.

Comment: My file says andoid_r11-sdk-windows{1} and the sdk is not in a specific file. It's just in that area. When I tried to paste it to file, eclipse still couldn't see it.

Comment: You should download the SDK from the [Android Page](http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r11-windows.exe).

Comment: After installing the SDK just point Eclipse to the folder of the SDK. More infos on installation can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)